# Porque el android no me bota ningún tipo de error cuando consumo un json, utilizo wamp server y retrofit para consumir el json

Tags: java, android, retrofit

El json que estoy utilizando ya lo he probado con postman y esta correcto, entonces no se cual sería el error. Lo que he pensado es que sea la configuración del wamp server porque no conecta o el android no tiene salida para conectarse al wamp server, ¿a que se puede deber?

Comment: En el LogCat no te muestra algún error? estas seguro que estas imprimiendo el stacktrace al capturar un posible error? porque no agregas código de lo que realizas? saludos.

Comment: Amigo lo peor es que no me bota ningun error

Comment: Te sugiero revises los filtros de tu LogCat si es que no obtienes mensajes de error, asegura que, no tienes algún log al realizar la petición usando retrofit y cuando la petición falla?

Answer (score 1):

Deberías checkear la version de tu Android. Los dispositivos superior igual a la version 8 de android suspendieron las conexiones http. Al probar en un servidor local debes de estar usando este protocolo y por tanto no te funcionará. Para evadir esto debes hacer unas configuraciones  a tu app. Te sugiero esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54818098/cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)